# Python function with while loop and breaks to find consecutive count

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I have the following list:

```
my_list = ['UK', 'FR', 'UK','SP', 'CN', 'USA', 'UK']
```

I want to write a python function (preferably while loop with break) which counts the maximum consecutive values before you reach a "UK". So here the max would be 3.

Result:

```
['SP', 'CN', 'USA']
```

How would you go about this please?

Thank you,

Sam

Comment: You need to have a go. Do it in the most basic way you can imagine, then improve it. If you can’t work it out you’ll have a more dodging question.

Comment: Apologies, my phone corrected a word to "dodging", but I'm not sure what it was beforehand. Perhaps "focused": *If you can’t work it out you’ll have a more focused question.*

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) works for this.

```
import itertools

my_list = ['UK', 'FR', 'UK','SP', 'CN', 'USA', 'UK']
groupedby = [tuple(grp) for val,grp in itertools.groupby(my_list, key=lambda elem:elem == 'UK')]
most_consecutive_values = max(groupedby, key=len)
# ('SP', 'CN', 'USA')
max_consecutive_values = len(most_consecutive_values)
# 3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the accumulate() function (from itertools) to progressively count the number of non-UK elements in the list resetting the count to zero at each occurrence of UK:

If you only need the maximum count, you can use the max() function on the result:

```
my_list = ['UK','FR', 'UK','SP', 'CN', 'USA', 'UK']

from itertools import accumulate
maxCount    = max(accumulate((int(e!="UK") for e in my_list),lambda n,m:(n+m)*m))
print(maxCount) #3
```

If you also need to get the list of elements in that largest group, you can place the counts in a list and use it to figure out the positions

```
groupCounts = list(accumulate((int(e!="UK") for e in my_list),lambda n,m:(n+m)*m))
maxCount    = max(groupCounts)
group       = my_list[:groupCounts.index(maxCount)+1][-maxCount:]
print(maxCount,group) # 3 ['SP', 'CN', 'USA']
```

For a more basic loop structure, you could do this:

```
maxGroup = []
group    = []
for element in my_list:
    group = (group+[element])*(element != "UK")
    if len(group)>len(maxGroup):
        maxGroup=group
print(len(maxGroup),maxGroup) # 3 ['SP', 'CN', 'USA']
```

Note that you need to go through all the data to figure out the largest group, there is not opportunity to `break` early.